# New navigation bar on iphone - cannot click right side buttons after zoom

Tags: bug, status-declined, top-bar

I have traditionally used the web interface to SO on my iPhone, and then pinch to zoom if there is something I need to see/click.  This includes the "Recent inbox messages" and "Recent achivements" buttons.

After the redesign of the navigation bar I cannot do this.  The navigation bar moves slower than the rest of the page so after zooming I cannot get all the way to the right side where the buttons are.[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't support zoom or the use of the full site on a mobile browser.

Answer (score -1):

Stack Overflow (and also other sites in the network) is not responsive, however it has separate mobile-friendly theme to use on phones. It should load automatically and if it doesn't please tap "mobile" link in footer.

New header is sticky (fixed) by default. Elements like that don't play well with zooming / pitching / scrolling interactions. That being said, if you really need it on phone, you can disable "stickiness" in your preferences.

Comment: The mobile version is worthless for power users. For starters, it doesn't provide access to the review queues.